# UI5 - navTo doesnt launch onInit event on page which wasnt displayed yet

Tags: routes, sapui5

I have a UI5 application with 3 levels

1. /home

landing page, which, among other things, displays several item. On the left, there is a navigation panel which contains the link to the list of all items. Navigation panel is done by `<tnt:NavigationList>` controls which have property `itemSelect=onItemSelect`. This `onItemSelect` function looks like this

```
        onItemSelect: function (oEvent) {
            const item = oEvent.getParameter('item');
            this.getRouter().navTo(item.getKey());
        },
```

2. /home/items

list of all item. Each item can be clicked. On the controller of this item list, there is an `onInit` function which loads the list of items from the database

3. /home/items/{itemId} - item details

The problem is that the *onInit()* on the items list in not always executed. If I open the landing page (level 1) and then click on the side navigation to display the items list (level 2), *onInit()* is executed and all data are successfully loaded.

However, I have also an option to open landing page (level 1) and from there, click on a few newest items to display their details directly (level 3), bypassing the whole items list. And then, if I click on the side navigation to display the items list (level 2), the *onInit()* is not executed and the list stays empty.

Can someone explain to me why is this happening and how to fix it?

I understand that *onInit()* is executed only once, but I don't understand why it isn't executed on the page which is going to be displayed for the first time.

Comment: `onInit` is essentially the constructor. Most things in your app are not even ready at this point. It fires once, and generally before the router is started. A better bet, if you're using the router like you seem to, is `this.getRouter().getRoute('routename').attachPatternMatched(function(oEvent)...`. Put it in your controller's `onInit`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, problem solved. As I said, the problem was that the onInit was not even executed. It was caused by a bug I made, forgot to change the initial line when I was copypasting the code - so both items list and items details were extending the same controller in the beginning, forgot to rewrite the code for item details.

```
`return BaseController.extend('xxx.portal.controller.item.itemList', {
```

So if the item details were displayed earlier than the items list, they also called the controller for the items list and it wasn´t called when the actual items list was displayed

Answer (score 0):

example coding from jorgs suggestion:

navigation:

```
onPress: function (oEvent) {
        var oItem = oEvent.getSource();
        var oRouter = sap.ui.core.UIComponent.getRouterFor(this);
        oRouter.navTo("detail", {
            invoicePath: oItem.getBindingContext("invoice").getPath().substr(1)
        });
    }
```

onInit in Controller:

```
    sap.ui.define([
"sap/ui/core/mvc/Controller"], function (Controller) {
"use strict";
return Controller.extend("sap.ui.demo.wt.controller.Detail", {
    onInit: function () {
        var oRouter = sap.ui.core.UIComponent.getRouterFor(this);
        oRouter.getRoute("detail").attachPatternMatched(this._onObjectMatched, this);
    },
    _onObjectMatched: function (oEvent) {
        this.getView().bindElement({
            path: "/" + oEvent.getParameter("arguments").invoicePath,
            model: "invoice"
        });
    }
});
```

});

--> source: https://help.sap.com/doc/saphelp_uiaddon20/2.05/en-US/23/66345a94f64ec1a80f9d9ce50a59ef/content.htm?no_cache=true